How to mock a static method call inside another static class using Mockito in Java?
I have a Java class OuterClass with a static method getInnerClass(). I want to write a unit test for a method that invokes getInnerClass().getType() and mock the behavior of getType().
Here's a simplified version of the code:
public class OuterClass {
    public static InnerClass getInnerClass() {
        // Do Something
    }
    
    public static class InnerClass {
        private String type;

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
    }
}

I'm trying to test a method that calls OuterClass.getInnerClass().getType(), but I don't want to execute the logic inside getInnerClass() during the test, i.e test should not go inside getInnerClass() and return the result to the next chained function to invoke getType(). How can I achieve this using Mockito or any other mocking framework?
I've tried using Mockito to mock the getType() method of InnerClass, but since getInnerClass() is a static method, it gets called during the test execution, leading to undesired behavior. I'm looking for a way to mock the getType() method without invoking the static method getInnerClass().
Environment

JUnit 5
Spring Boot 3

I tried below snippets
@MockBean
private PlatformContextHolder platformContextHolder;

@Test
public void method() throws Exception {
    OuterClass.InnerClass responseMock = mock(OuterClass.InnerClass.class);
    
    when(outerClass.getInnerClass()).thenReturn(responseMock);
    doReturn("result").when(responseMock).getType();
    
    String result = OuterClass.getInnerClass().getType();
    
    // Verify that the mock behavior is as expected
    assertEquals("mockedType", result);
}

I also tried the mockStatic methods, but that wasn't successful.

Can you redesign your code to become testable? Singletons are inherently difficult to test, since they are effectively modern globals.

I would have done that, but this is coming from an external library which we don't have much control on. In that case, it is extremely important to make it work with some fix.

You don't have to redesign the external library, but you can redesign how your code uses the external library. Don't access the singleton directly, but wrap it in your own dependency. Then swap this dependency wtih a test double.
